# Simplify Map on a list of lists

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, map, precedence

I have the following example list of matrices:

```
a = {p Table[RandomComplex[], {2}, {2}], q Table[RandomComplex[], {2}, {2}]}
```

where p and q are real variables. I would like to take the `ConjugateTranspose` to each element of the list. This can be achieved using the `Map` function:

```
Assuming[{p, q} \[Element] Reals, Simplify@ConjugateTranspose /@ hbasisMats]
```

However, this does not apply the real assumption requirement. How to edit the above to achieve this?

Comment: Ttry: `Simplify[ConjugateTranspose /@ a, {p, q} \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: @DanielHuber, that appears to work as expected. Is it since the assumption is incorporated in the `Simplify`? Is this the preferred approach to specify `Assumptions`?

Comment: Look up Simplify in the help. Simplify takes assumptions from its second argument and not from $Assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaken the precedence of the operators. [See here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html).

The way you are writing your expression is not what you expect. You are asking *Mathematica* to [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) the function [`ConjugateTranspose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConjugateTranspose.html), not your expression.

```
Assuming[
   Element[
      Alternatives[p, q]
      , Reals
   ], 
    Map[
       Simplify[ConjugateTranspose]
       , a
    ]
]
```

Probably you mean this

```
Assuming[{p, q} ∈ Reals, Simplify[ConjugateTranspose /@ a]]
```

or

```
Assuming[{p, q} ∈ Reals, Simplify@Map[ConjugateTranspose, a]]
```

or

```
Assuming[{p, q} ∈ Reals, Simplify@*ConjugateTranspose /@ a]
```